# Unity I/O with Android device

Tags: android, io, unity-game-engine, device

i can read and write file with this method for storing game progres.

```
filePath = Application.dataPath + "/";
filenam= "SavedGame";
extension = ".txt";

Lettura ----------------
var FRead = new File.OpenText(filePath + fileNam + extension);

for (var i : int= 0; i<N; i++) {

FRead.ReadLine();

}
Scrittura--------------------
var FWrite: StreamWriter = new StreamWriter(filePath + filenam + extension);
FWrite.WriteLine("AAAA");
```

A run time in the Unity editor all work perfectly.

But in Android device Application.dataPath seems dont work.

I tryed Application.persistentDataPath that work fine but in (Read Only),but i need place the SavedGame.txt manually in the patch.

I tried a fantomatic  "jar:file://" + Application.dataPath + "!/assets/"; but dont work.

Note when i build the project in apk packege semms dont appear my SavedGame.txt,that
in the editor is in UnityProject\Assets .

Come posso risalire al percorso giusto del mio  SavedGame.txt, posizionato in ad esempio in  UnityProject\Assets nei device?

How i cand do this in a correct way read and write SavedGame.txt in android device?

Comment: "dont work" is not a problem description. What is happening? Do you get an error?

Answer (score 0):

On android you might not have direct write access to the dataPath of the project.

Try using [Application.persistentDataPath](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html) instead. This is where save files are intended to be stored.

Change:

```
filePath = Application.dataPath + "/";
```

to

```
filePath = Application.persistentDataPath + "\\";
```